# I can't open more instances of android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, bluestacks

**My PC specs** :

**Graphic card** - RTX 4090(Latest drivers)

**CPU** - Ryzen 9 7950X

**Motherboard** - X670e-f Rog strix

**Ram**- DDR5 64gb 6000Mhz CL32

**Monitor** - LG C2 48 4K HDR OS - Windows 10 Pro

**Screenshots** :

**LDplayer** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cthm.jpg

**Bluestacks** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/okeL6.jpg

I've seen people run 20-40 emulators(**OpenGL**) at once with way older rigs but I'm not able to open more than 10-15 instances(each instance has been set to 2gb/1 core & 20-30fps) on **my new high end PC** which I've built few weeks ago. I used to run 12-16 on my RTX 2060, Ryzen 4800h laptop. One of the reasons I've got this build is to run 20-30 instances at once. I've tried various Android emulators but it's the same problem everywhere, after opening 10-15 instances it shows **OpenGL version too low or Failed to initialize graphics backend for D3D11** errors. There's definitely something I'm missing. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me with this problem. I'm at my wit's end here.

1.) Is there a limit to OpenGL rendering in virtual machines?

2.) Does virtual memory has anything to do with it?

3.) Should I enable HyperV and hardware acceleration?

I've used tried to **DirectX** option on MEMU emulator, i was able to open 20-25 instances with it but DirectX can't run the applications i use. In **OpenGl**, i was not able to open more than 10-13 instances.is there something that's stopping OpenGl from rendering more? None of my components are overloaded while opening these instances, the task manager shows very low utilization percentages. i can't see where the problem is. Can anyone help me identify the problem?